# Java. Convert string to dotted IP address

Tags: java, oracle, ip

I retrieve IP addresses from table using query (oracle, pl/sql):

```
String selectTableSQL = "SELECT IP "
                      + "FROM table";

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);
```

I receive strings this way:

```
String ip = rs.getString("IP");
```

Here is my problem: some ip addresses (received strings) look like `-1402732545` but some like `16711681`. How to convert them to dotted ip addresses (172.20.10.226)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @BackSlash, be lenient...

Comment: BackSlash, this is an example how I would like to receive ip addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the IP address as an integer value, guava has [InetAddresses](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InetAddresses.html) -

```
String addressStr = InetAddresses.fromInteger(Integer.parseInt(ip)).getHostAddress();
```

Or, using only regular Java code,

```
String addressStr = InetAddress.getByAddress(BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(ip))
    .toByteArray()).getHostAddress();
```

Comment: Elliott Frisch, I tried second method but got an error: No suitable method found for `valueOf(String)`. Can you help me to fix this?

Comment: @user3649515 Edited. I missed a `Integer.parseInt()` in there.

Comment: Elliott Frisch, I edited but there is another error: ip is of illegal length

Answer (score 2):

You actually want to convert number to human readable IP address. Take a look on this article for details. http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-ip-address-to-decimal-number/